# PowerShell - SQL tables as input to foreach command to corresponding files - 'System.Data.DataRow'

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am working on an array of files that match the names of tables in our SQL Server database. I want to query a subset of those tables, and use those table names to provide commands to their corresponding files.

Example, there is a customer table in SQL Server, so I have a customer.dat datafile.

I have queried 3 tables from SQL Server, and would like to use them to give commands to their 3 corresponding datafiles, but this is the output I get:

```
$Tables = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Inputfile $inputfile `
    -ServerInstance $server `
    -Database $Database `
    -OutputAs DataRows

$Tables.ForEach({Write-Host $Tables.Item(0)})
```

Output:
[image]

For some reason, the output for all 3 tables comes out as 'System.Data.Datarow'. How do I get the values from this data?

I eventually want to put the desired output into a string for a dynamic filepath. Something like:

```
$Tables.ForEach({Get-ChildItem -Path $filepath\$_.dat})
```

But it gives me an error with a similar problem:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'filepath\System.Data.DataRow.dat' because it does not exist.
```

You see, it is inserting 'System.Data.DataRow' into the file name instead of the intended table name.
Any help, or overview of the concepts I am attempting to use would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: If you have a collection of `DataRow` instances then `$Tables.ForEach({Write-Host $Tables.Item(0)})` should just be `$Tables.ForEach({ $_ })` to enumerate each row and `$Tables.ForEach({ Get-ChildItem -Path "$filepath\$($_.dat)" })` for the other part, assming `.dat` is an actual column

Comment: Thank you for your response, the Get-ChildItem command you provided gives me the entire directory of files. I need only the 3 files corresponding with the 3 SQL tables defined in $Tables

Comment: This only output the implied `ToString()` result of the **first** DataRow. If you changed `$Tables.Item(0)` to `$_` you would see the same text, but at least then it would be the implied `ToString()` result of **each** row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Santiago for helping with with some subtle adjustments with the syntax. I was able to adjust it further with the following:

```
$Tables.ForEach({Get-ChildItem -Path "$filepath\$($_.item(0)).dat"})
```

The addition of .item(0) let the table values appear into the command.

Output:
[image]